# How to get Youtube Thumbnails

Tags: ios, youtube-api, screenshot

I have made an RSS reader app in Xcode, which gets it's information from a YouTube channel. How can I get the thumbails from the videos?

I am able to use this link: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/HaatFilms/uploads?alt=rss

To get the uploads text, but what would I use to get the thumbnail for each specific video?

Comment: But how can I find the Video ID of a Video and then display it in a tableView?

Comment: Using that RSS feed?  There's a proper API for youtube.

Answer (score 18):

Using the listed RSS feed:

You'll see links that include:

```
LKk6SvGmJj4
```

> Previous episode: http://youtu.be/**LKk6SvGmJj4**
>   http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/**LKk6SvGmJj4**

That's the youtube ID.

Take that ID and use it with a straight image tag.

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/LKk6SvGmJj4/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/LKk6SvGmJj4/1.jpg
```

Use those images to populate your tables.  Personally, I use Afnetworking's UIImageView category.

> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
 [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/LKk6SvGmJj4/1.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category to load image to an `UIImageView`. [UIImageView+AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html)

```
NSString * youtubeID = @"TJkmc8-eyvE";
NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/0.jpg",youtubeId];

[imageView setImageWithURL:youtubeURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage"]];
```

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy, When I Tried it.. It didn't work. Am I supposed to add something else other than the stated code above?

Comment: yeah you need to add afnetworking to load images asynchronous in you app. What error you are getting